# Two step layout for multiple modules in php?

Tags: php, architecture

I am creating a web application in PHP. It is built with multiple independent modules. For the sake of example, let's say there is an email module and file explorer module. Each of them have physically separate folders with different libraries etc. However, in the frontend they both have the same interface (navigation is the same and content in the center is changing).

I want to centralize my interface in the backend. How could I create some kind of two step layout so whatever app is called on the backend, the content of it is merged with outer interface and then sent back.

I want to make this because if there is a change in the outer interface, I have to copy code in all of the modules.

Below is the example mockup to show you what I mean. Content interface is changing and static outer interface is always the same no matter the app that is chosen.

How could I achieve something this elegant?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be worthwhile spending some time seeing how likes of Laravel 4 and other similar frameworks achieve this (if you haven't already that is).

For example in Laravel 4 it is reasonably easy to separate an application's business logic into modules, and share certain parts of the views across these modules using layouts, eg. you can create a master layout template that includes the master static outer interface as you show above, and then each of the individual module templates can extend this with a simple

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

at the top of each of the content interface views. More details here - http://laravel.com/docs/templates

I am not suggesting that you use Laravel, but it is likely that you can find the answer to your question in one of the existing php frameworks - even if you copy their solutions rather than adopting the framework it may be quicker than reinventing the wheel :-)

Glen